# Adding a SQL WHERE clause into linQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using VS 2013 (VB).

I have the following linq query

```
Dim countCompanies = (From num In db.GasEmailAddresses
                              Group Join GCC In db.GasCompanies
                              On num.CompanyID Equals GCC.ID
                              Into GCComp = Group
                              Select num.CompanyID).Distinct.Count
```

Which returns 4 results.  I want to add a where clause along the lines of

```
WHERE GCC.Active = 1
```

I have been messing with this bit of code for a bit now and cant seem to get it to work.

Any ideas?

---UPDATE---

Revised code based on suggestion

```
    Dim countCompanies = (From num In db.GasEmailAddresses
                          Group Join GCC In db.GasCompanies.Where(Function(y) y.Active = 1)
                          On num.CompanyID Equals GCC.ID
                          Into GCComp = Group
                          Select num.CompanyID).Distinct.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering out while retrieving the data source:-

```
companies.Where(Function(x) x.Active = 1)
```

Comment: nope, I still get 4 results and I would expect to get 3 as I flagged a company as inactive i.e. 0

Comment: @user2050577 - Where did you applied the filter? Say, if db.GasCompanies was earlier returning 5 records than after filter if any active flag is zero this count should be less. Please re-check.

Comment: I have edited my post to show how I added in your suggestion.

Comment: @user2050577 - It's really difficult to answer your question without knowing the actual Data Source. Please provide sample values of `db.GasCompanies` & `db.GasEmailAddresses`.